# proposal not funded in pallet_treasury

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, pallet-treasury

I am using pallet_treasury. I have created proposal and verified it. I have set [`SpendPeriod`](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/blob/a9ef41ac23a18df9bad800f9a5d4929daf082323/runtime/src/lib.rs#L711) in min. Even after 1 min proposal doesn't get funded. What I am missing here? Why it's not working? Someone please give some advice.

[spend_period_video_link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dQjn2W0cKJ8pz4EHPTvaQLgnENWCH2sW/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your Treasury does not have any funds.

Try `Balances::force_set` the Treasury account.